# Where I'm wrong? Why my answer is different from the book?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

The question is to integrate 
$$\int x\cos^{-1}x dx$$

Answer in my book

$$(2x^2-1)\frac{\cos^{-1}x}{4}-\frac{x}{4}\sqrt{1-x^2}+C$$

I'm learning single variable calculus right now and at current about integration with part. I'm confused in a problem from sometime. I don't know where I am wrong. Please have a look at the images.[image: Image 1][image: Image 2]

> **Solution.** $\newcommand{\dd}{\; \mathrm{d}}$
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> &\cos^{-1} x \int x \dd x - \int \left[\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdot\frac{x^2}2\right] \dd x=\\
> =&\cos^{-1}x \cdot \frac{x^2}2 + \int \frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}} \dd x2=\\
> =&\frac{x^2}2 \cdot \cos^{-1}x + \frac12 \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \dd x =
> \begin{vmatrix}x=\sin t\\ \dd x=\cos t\dd t\end{vmatrix} = \\
> =&\frac{x^2\cos^{-1}x}2 + \frac12 \int \frac{\sin^2t \cos t}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2t}} \dd t =\\
> =&\frac{x^2\cos^{-1}x}2 + \frac12 \int \frac{\sin^2t \cos t}{\cos t} \dd t =\\
> =&\frac{x^2\cos^{-1}x}2 + \frac12 \int \sin^2t \dd t =\\
> =&\frac{x^2\cos^{-1}x}2 + \frac12 \int \frac{1-\cos2t}2 \dd t =\\
> =&\frac{x^2\cos^{-1}x}2 + \frac12 \int \frac12 \dd t -\frac 14 \int \cos2t \dd t =\\
> =&\frac{x^2\cos^{-1}x}2 + \frac14 t - \frac18 \sin 2t + C =\\
> =&\frac{x^2\cos^{-1}x}2 + \frac14 \sin^{-1}x - \frac18 \sin2\sin^{-1}x + C =\\
> =&\frac{x^2\cos^{-1}x}2 + \frac14 \sin^{-1}x - \frac18 \sin(2\sin^{-1}x) + C
> \end{align}
> $$

Please help. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: I honestly did not look at your work. My class is coming up. I am just giving you a suggestion. Do a u-sub $arccosx=t$ The integral then becomes of the form $cost*sint*t$ which through the double angle formula becomes of the form $t*sin2t$ Integration by parts on this integral is way easier than working with the arccos stuff...

Comment: Are you *sure* your answer is *really* different from the book's answer? (Try plotting the difference with WolframAlpha, for example!)

Comment: better do a change of variables first like $\theta = cos^{-1}x$

Comment: I have tried to transcribe the math from your picture. Please check whether I did not change something by mistake. (I had a difficult time reading your handwriting at some places.) Having it in text form rather than a picture also makes it easier for you if you need to edit something. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is not false, but you didn't thoroughly simplify.

This is why both answers are the same:

1. $\arcsin x+\arccos x=\dfrac\pi2$
2. $\sin(2\arcsin x)=2\sin(\arcsin x)\cos(\arcsin x)=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}.$

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Bernard's answer you can further transform your term

\begin{align}
\int x \cos^{-1}(x)dx&=\frac{x^2\cos^{-1}x}2 + \frac14 \sin^{-1}x - \frac18 \sin(2\sin^{-1}x)\\
&=\frac{x^2\cos^{-1}x}2 + \frac14 \sin^{-1}x - \frac 14 x\sqrt{1-x^2}+c \ \text{ but this does not equal}\\
&\neq (2x^2-1)\frac{\cos^{-1}x}{4}-\frac{x}{4}\sqrt{1-x^2}+c \\&=\frac{x^2\cos^{-1}x}2 - \frac14 \cos^{-1}x - \frac 14 x\sqrt{1-x^2}+c
\end{align}

so additionally to the fact that you can further *simplify* your answer the given **answer in the book is wrong**.